# Chamar Modal e Tooltip no mesmo data-toggle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Tenho um botão que chama uma modal assim:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#revisao>Revisao</button>
```

Para chamar um Tooltip usa-se:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>
```

Como chamar a Modal e o Tooltip no mesmo botão?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deixe a mesma estrutura da modal, inclua apenas um novo `data-type`  que será o seu `data-toogle`, no meu exemplo, usei `data-tt="tooltip"` agora é só adicionar o `title` e chamar no js.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$("[data-tt=tooltip]").tooltip();
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<br><br>

<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-tt="tooltip" title="Olá Mundo!">Modal</a>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito e simples.

Answer (score 2):

Uma opção que não envolve alteração no nome do data-attribute nem no javascript, é envolver o elemento de trigger (o botão no caso) em outro elemento que seja inline, fazendo dele um tipo de "wrapper":

```html
<span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#revisao">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Revisao</button>
</span>
```